# Shortcode or PHP inside a shortcode in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

On a php page in wordpress, I have a shortcode for an accordion, that consists of the following, and works perfectly:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[su_accordion]
[su_spoiler title="Feature Locations" style="fancy"] CONTENT GOES HERE
[/su_spoiler]
[/su_accordion]'); ?>
```

Within the accordion, I want to display an interactive map, which can be displayed using either a shortcode, or PHP. Both options are:

```
[show-map id='1'], or
<?php build_i_world_map(1); ?>
```

When I insert either of these into the accordion shortcode, the map does not display. However, outside of the accordion, the second option above (with php) displays successfully.

What am I missing in terms of including this in the shortcode for the accordion?

Answer (score 0):

In your example your outer section should be like

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[su_accordion]
[su_spoiler title="Feature Locations" style="fancy"]'. build_i_world_map(1) .'
[/su_spoiler]
[/su_accordion]'); ?>
```

In wordpress you should call `do_shortcode()` for shortcode calls.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[show-map id='1']"); ?>
```

[do_shortcode() reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/)

Comment: Thank you. When I put that exact code into the content portion of the accordion shortcode, I end up with the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' ... on line 46. I don't get this error otherwise.

Comment: I think I get it now, updated answer based on your feedback.

Comment: Actually, I got it working. Using the outer section you modified above, I was able to simple insert the shortcode without PHP around it into the content section. All good now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

this is an effective way to include a concatenating inside a shortcode function

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[download url='.$next_attachment_url.']'); ?>
```